How to prove $ (x + y)^+ = x^+ + y^+ $ in Riesz Space holds for disjoint $x, y$?
I can see that $| x + y | = |x| + |y| $ holds if $x, y$ are disjoint. But unable to deduce further.

For all $x$ we have $x=x^+-x^-$ and $|x|=x^++x^-$.
From $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ you get
$$
(1) \quad ~~~ (x+y)^++(x+y)^-= x^+ + x^- + y^+ + y^-,
$$
and $(x+y)=x+y$ can be written as
$$
(2) \quad ~~~ (x+y)^+-(x+y)^-= x^+ - x^- + y^+ - y^-.
$$
Now $(1)+(2)$ (and division by $2$) yields
$$
(x+y)^+= x^+ +  y^+.
$$
